# get the size of class object at run time in objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, malloc

I need to get the size of class object. For e.g.

```
Class ABC
{
   NSData *data;
   UIimage *img;
   NSString *str;
}
```

At run time i assign values to .data and .img properties for e.g.

```
ABC *objABC = [ABC allc] init];
objABC.data = Mydata;
objABC.img = Myimage;
objABC.str = @"testString";
```

Now, i need to know the size in Bytes or KB or MB of "objABC".

Suppose i have created 100 objects of Class ABC with different size of .image and .data properties. I have tried with malloc_size(), but it returns me the same size for all my objects regardless of the size .data or .img

I want to know the exact size of objABC in KB. Please help.

Comment: You need to write a method inside ABC that returns the size of its content, then write suitable logic within that method.

Comment: Make a method inside that object that returns a double. Inside it convert self to nsdata and from nsdata get the length, return the length.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the following:

```
#include <objc/runtime.h>

size_t objsize = class_getInstanceSize([objABC class]);
```

Comment: This will only get the size of all instance variables, not the size of the objects pointed to by those instance variables.